# Set String to whichever value is not null

Tags: java

I have 2 string variables `autoCollateral` and `secureCollateral`. I need to set the value of `collateral` to have the value of the variable that has a non-null value.

I wrote the code as

```
if(autoCollateral!=null){
  collateral=autoCollateral
} 
if(secureCollateral!=null){
  collateral=secureCollateral
}.
```

If both has value I need to set any of them...what is the most optimized way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax wise it will be

```
collateral = autoCollateral!=null ? autoCollateral : secureCollateral
```

Comment: I would test for `== null` and reverse the operands. Always make positive tests if you can - it's good coding style.

Comment: @Bohemian Provide some source?

Comment: @Bohemian I also prefer that way, I just used the condition mentioned my OP for her clarity. However I also think it's a matter of personal taste rather than a good style.

Comment: @Thihara to nit pick on this answer that is written 4 years ago... your code does not have the exact same meaning as what the OP posted :) i.e. in the case secureCollateral is also null.

Comment: @Vikas Yes, it does. Read again :P

Comment: @Thihara The ternary operation you wrote exactly translates into this.
if(autoCollateral!=null){
  collateral=autoCollateral
} 
else{
  collateral=secureCollateral
}

Comment: @Vikas Read the last line of the question.`If both has value I need to set any of them`. Preferably before raising a 4 year old question from the dead.

Comment: @Thihara Yup I read the entire question before writing my first comment and rising the question from the dead. Let me make my point totally clear this time. The last line says, if both have a value, i.e if none of them is null, set to any of them. But it doesn’t say anything about what to do when both are null. According to the OP code, if both are null, collateral value is not changed. But according to your code, collateral value is set to null in the case where both are null. So if both are null, your code sets collateral to null even if it had a valid value before coming to this point.

Comment: @Vikas You said in your first comment that my answer doesn't have the exact meaning as the OPs code. I don't see OP's code handling a scenario where both variables are null. If you are telling me that the `collateral` variable can have an existing value that should be preserved in the case  where both `autoCollateral` and `secureCollateral` is null, that's not mentioned in OP's question. So <shrug>Don't care!</shrug> :-D